Data inputs for Sankey Chart in Vega on PowerBI Deneb
I am trying to create a similar visual as in this link below in Deneb PowerBI:Sankey charts (allvuial charts) - By PBI - Davide. I see that the data is entered manually inside in the form of JSON such as:
"data": [
    {
      "name": "input",
      "values": [
        {
          "category": "Server Products & Cloud",
          "stack": 1,
          "sort": 1,
          "labels": "left"
        },
        {
          "category": "Enterprise Services",
          "stack": 1,
          "sort": 2,
          "labels": "left",
          "gap": 20
        },
        {
          "category": "Office Products",
          "stack": 1,
          "sort": 3,
          "labels": "left"
        }
}

In PowerBI, the data is imported in the form of
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "dataset"
    } 
}

Is there a way to somehow use the values from "dataset" of PowerBI fields (taking advantage of the filter context to derive specific values) in the "name":"input" fields.
For example : I want to achieve something like this
"data": [
{
  "name": "dataset"
},
{
  "name": "input",
  "values": [
    {
      "category": "Server Products & Cloud",
      "stack": "datum['Measure1']",  //Custom value from PowerBI measures
      "sort": 1,
      "labels": "left"
    },
    {
      "category": "Enterprise Services",
      "stack": "datum['Measure2']",  //Custom value from PowerBI measures
      "sort": 2,
      "labels": "left",
      "gap": 20
    },
    {
      "category": "Office Products",
      "stack":"datum['Measure3']",  //Custom value from PowerBI measures
      "sort": 3,
      "labels": "left"
    }
}

However, its not allowing me to do so. I an very new to Vega and I think there is a different way to reference these values.

There are two reports in the .pbix. Inline has inline data like you say but the second report named Data Driven already does what you ask.

Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thats a really great visual that you have built.
